# Which telephoto lens should I get for Nikon D3000 to take close-ups?

Tags: nikon, telephoto, lens-recommendation

Context:

- I have a Nikon D3000 with its kit lens, 18 to 55mm,  f3.5-5.6.
- I find that I am not getting close enough to subjects and want to force myself to get more close ups by getting a telephoto or zoom that starts no wider than 50mm (equiv)
- I don't like carrying a lot of equipment
- I want to spend $200 to $350

I would appreciate it if you could you recommend a choice of lens for me!!

Thanks

Comment: 70-200mm is a common size, you might want to rethink the "not less than 50" requirement. So you have gap, big deal, at those distances take a few steps forward or backwards.

Comment: +1 to Paul - you really don't find many telephoto lenses starting below 70. 70-200 or 70-300 are quite common, and you can find budget (but still decent) lenses for around $250. Personally I have a Tamron, which I find good if a little slow.

Comment: @Paul 70-200mm (105-300mm equiv) is _longer_, but not _wider_ than 50mm equiv, and therefore would fit the question just fine

Comment: @Imre, correct! Thanks all for your feedback. What do you think about a non-zoom as an option? Forces me to work within that artistic constraint, and I get a faster lens for the money. Good tradeoff or bad idea?

Comment: Yes, primes are wonderful. Especially in macro photography. In telephoto usage, though, "zooming with feet" might mean a long way to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nikkor 18-55 has minimum focusing distance of 0.9 feet (0.28 m); if you really want to **get closer**, you'll need a macro lens. There are very few options in this price range. There's the [Nikkor AF-S 40mm f/2.8](http://www.photozone.de/nikon--nikkor-aps-c-lens-tests/674-afs40f28dx). Other options, such as a used Nikkor 60mm f/2.8 Micro or a new Sigma 50mm f/2.8 Macro, would leave you with manual focus (which is actually quite okay for close-up shots).

However, if you meant that you want to **magnify your subjects more** *without* actually getting closer to them, these focal lengths will obviously be too short (you already have those). If you had asked for image quality and low light performance, I would have suggested the Rokinon 85mm f/1.4, which is praised for those properties, but its rather heavy weight (1.4 lb / 635 g) and lack of AF will probably put you off. I don't know any other primes worth considering in your price class (the [Nifty Fifty](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/should-i-buy-this-nikon-50mm-f-1-8) is *cheaper* and not longer than your kit zoom).

So in this case, you're left with zooms. On Nikon, I have only used 70-300 VR which was quite impressive for its focusing speed and image quality, and it seems to be available [$380 used](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/800819580-USE/Nikon_2161_AF_S_VR_Zoom_NIKKOR_70_300mm.html). Perhaps your budget can be stretched a little or some hunting around will find a better deal.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Nikon D3000 I purchased in September 2010 that only came with the 18-55mm kit lens.

In December 2010, I purchased a Tamron 70-300mm lens as my close-up telephoto that I purchased for around $200 and I'm very happy with since I didn't want to spend more than $200.  I made sure it had the auto-focus motor in the lens because the D3000 doesn't have an auto-focus motor.

The only negative comment I have on my Tamron 70-300mm lens (f/4.5-f/5.6) is it slow to auto-focus when trying to capture things that are moving, but I think that is more due to my limited photographic ability.

[Here's a shot I took at the Taronga Western Plains Zoo at Dubbo with my lens](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-sGU9T4N4sGU/UIPD1Uw5MzI/AAAAAAAABfs/r0mlJtuxOh4/s1241/2012roadtrip__20120930__dubbo_zoo__taken_by_J___00105.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which kind of subjects you are aiming for (people?) but I'd recommend the [Nikon 55-300](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2197/AF-S-NIKKOR-55-300mm-f%252F4.5-5.6G-ED-VR.html?cid=55300mmfom), falls within that price range and gives you plenty of zoom. You can find it cheaper than the price on Nikon site.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's people that I am aiming for. Also, what about a non-zoom? Pros / Cons in your opinion?

Comment: What does everyone think of this one:

http://www.amazon.com/Nikon-55-300mm-4-5-5-6G-ED-VR/dp/B003ZSHNCC/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1323383222&sr=1-2

Looks like it meets my needs nicely. But you might have a counter suggestion or information that would be relevant... Thanks!!

Comment: That's quite cheap. I forgot this one has image stabilization which is a good thing too. I recommend it better than others of similar price like the Sigma 70-300. The Nikon 70-300 has better image quality but it's heavier (may concern you) and more expensive. The Nikon 55-200 is cheaper but going to 300 is nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative for the above mentioned zoom lenses I would like to mention the Tamron 90mm f2.8 Macro lens. It relatively small and lightweight, has excellent optic qualities and is great for both portraits and macro.

(Edit: not sure if it is within your budget)

Comment: Do you mean the Tamron 90mm f/2.8 macro? I don't think there's a Tokina 90mm f/2.8 lens. There's a Tokina 90mm f/2.5 macro, introduced in 1986 and is currently discontinued; and a Tokina 100mm f/2.8 macro.

Comment: Oops, yes it's the Tamron. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Go get a Nikon [55-300mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/b003zshncc)

Relatively,

- It's cheap,
- It's lightweight,
- It does its job perfectly ...

But, hey remember, it's NOT a Macro lens